# Is there any way to customize Windows command line's Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

The windows command line prompt display the full path of the currently directory, which will be too long when I am deep into a directory, like:

```
V:\Runtimes\ProjectName\src\ToolsTest\JavaCrashExample\JavaCrash\main\ToolsTest\JavaCrashExample\JavaCrash>
```

Is their any way to customized this, so that I can just display the current directory's name?

Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative you can also look at a CMD.exe replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772/cmd-exe-replacement.

Comment: I haven't found how to get the current folder name only, but you can cut it back to just `>` by typing `Prompt $g`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `prompt` command, which changes the displayed prompt.
Type `prompt /?` and you will get this:

```
C:\>PROMPT /?
Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.

PROMPT [text]

    text    Specifies a new command prompt

Prompt can be made of normal characters and the following special codes:

    $A    & (Ampersand)
    $B    | (Pipe)
    $C    ( (Left parenthesis)
    $D    Current date
    $E    Escape code (ASCII code 27)
    $F    ) (Right parenthesis)
    $G    > (Greater-than sign)
    $H    Backspace (erases previous character
    $L    < (Less-than sign)
    $N    Current drive
    $P    Current drive and path
    $Q    = (Equals sign)
    $S      (Space)
    $T    Current time
    $V    Windows version
    $_    Carriage return and linefeed
    $$    $ (Dollar sign)
```

If command extensions are enabled, there are a few more options, but these are the relevant ones.

In case you were wondering, the default prompt is: `prompt $P$G`,
and a BASH style prompt is: `prompt $$`.

The one that I use when I'm working in long directories is `prompt $G`, which is simply '`>`'.

Although there is no way to display just the current folder, you can always use `dir` to display folder information, including the path

Answer (score 2):

In the command prompt, type: `prompt /?`

That will give you a list of the options for customizing your prompt.  There doesn't appear to be an option for displaying only the current directory name.